# Ошибка - получаю null при попытке получить из базы данных Room список объектов через (объекты точно есть)

Tags: java, android, mvvm, android-room, repository

У меня прописаны методы в Dao, в Repository, в ViewModel и в Activity чтобы получить из Room базы список List,
но я получаю пустой список (ошибка attempt to invoke on a null Object reference)
Объекты такие точно есть, поскольку такой-же метод, только с LiveData -  работает,
т.е. метод LiveData<List> getNoobs выносит список всех noobs через observer.
Но в данном случае мне нужно просто получить список 5 случайных обектов без ЛивДата.
Получаю null. Где может быть ошибка?.. спасибо.

In PersonDao:

```
@Dao
public interface PersonDao {
    //other methods of PersonDao

    @Query("SELECT * FROM person_table WHERE status = :status ORDER BY RANDOM() LIMIT 5")
    List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom(String status);
}
```

In PersonRepository:

```
public class PersonRepository {
    private PersonDao mPersonDao;
    private List<Person> mFivePersonsFrom;

    //other methods

    List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom(String status) {
        PersonRoomDatabase.databaseWriteExecutor.execute(() -> {
            mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        });
        return mFivePersonsFrom;
    }
}
```

In PersonViewModel:

```
public class PersonViewModel extends AndroidViewModel {
    private PersonRepository mRepository;
    public List<Person> mFivePersonsFrom;
    public PersonViewModel(@NonNull Application application) {
        super(application);
        mRepository = new PersonRepository(application);
        mFivePersonsFrom = mRepository.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        //other methods
    }
    public List<Person> getFivePersonsFrom() {
        mRepository.getFivePersonsFrom("noob");
        return mFivePersonsFrom;
    }  
}
```

In MainActivity:

```
private CardStackView noobCardStackView;
private NoobAdapter noobAdapter;
List<Person> noobList;     
// other
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    noobViewModel = new ViewModelProvider(this,
            ViewModelProvider.AndroidViewModelFactory.getInstance(this.getApplication()))
            .get(PersonViewModel.class);
    noobList = noobiewModel.getFivePersonsFrom();
noobAdapter = new NoobAdapter(new NoobAdapter.NoobDiff(), noobList); 
    noobCardStackView.setAdapter(noobAdapter);
    // methods
}
```

Comment: Вы объявляете переменную `private List<Person> mFivePersonsFrom;`. После этого вызываете метод, из которой её возвращаете. Но нигде эту переменную не инициализируете. Потому и `null`. Ни разу за годы практики не встречал использование `databaseWriteExecutor` - возможно вам надо его убрать совсем и возвращать просто `mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom("noob")` из метода `getFivePersonsFrom()`. Учитывая, конечно, что без специального неодобряемого хака в главном потоке этого делать нельзя.

Comment: Когда я добавляю инициализирована в PersonRepository(Application application): "mFivePersonsFrom = mPersonDao.getFivePersonsFrom("noob"), получается другая ошибка: "Cannot access database on the main thread since it may potentially lock the UI for a long period of time.".... PS. А чем тогда направлять метод в другой поток если не Executor-ом? RXJava долго учить, наверняка есть что-то проще. AsynkTask-и - деприкейтед..

Comment: Не в главном потоке делать можно разными способами. Главное - в этом случае у вас не получится вызвать метод из главного потока и сразу в нём же получить результат. Как тут правильно сделать без RxJava?... Ну, возможно какая-то LiveData вам подойдёт.